# Listing all table on Postgres which has array datatype

Tags: postgresql

Since Kafka JDBC sink has some drawbacks for array datatype, i want to combine kafka JDBC sink connectors with simple kafka connectors which can support array datatype. However, I want to know which table in my source PostgreSQL has at least one column with array datatype so i can filter it from my kafka sink operation and switch them into simple kafka consumer operation, and to know the table which has number of array are pretty time consuming. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
select table_schema, table_name, column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
  and data_type = 'ARRAY';
```